# Rails, Conditional Stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, stylesheet

Want to include a conditional stylesheet for when the screen is a certain size, so
for example I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/responsive.css.scss" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)">
```

in the head. However it's being called despite the screen size being greater than 900px.

Is my mark-up incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: The stylesheet is always downloaded but the rules in it are only applied when the media query is satisfied. Are you sure the styles are applied or is the file only downloaded?

Comment: Styles are being applied regardless of wether the media query is satisfied or not!

Comment: If this worked, it would be a bad idea, as you'd have to load a stylesheet if the screen changed sizes through a browser resize event.

Comment: So instead of loading the css into the head i inserted it into the responsive css file with @media screen and (max-width: 900px) which seems to work!Thanks guys.